# Eclipse selection is null

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, selection, package-explorer

In my eclipse plugin I need to get the selection in the package explorer.
I found out that this works like this:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ISelectionService service = window.getSelectionService();
IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");
Object selection = structured.getFirstElement();
```

This works fine in 99% of all cases but I recently ran into a case where the `getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");` returns null although I can clearly see that I have something selected in the package explorer...

How can that be?

Comment: Are you sure it is the Package Explorer view and not Project Explorer which can look very similar?

Comment: Ehm... That could be a thing... Do some eclipse versions habe the project Explorer at the same position as the package Explorer?

Comment: I just found it out myself: Yes it is possible and yes it actually is the problem... If you post your comment as the answer I'll pick it as the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the view is not the Project Explorer rather than Package Explorer. They can look very similar and both default to appearing in the same place.